# Custom keyboard mappings

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard, keyboard-layout, keyboard-viewer

I have a PC with Linux Mint 19.2 installation that I set up a while ago. For that system, among other similar modifications, I figured out a way to remap one specific key combination: `Meta + ~` produces a ` (grave accent).

Recently I built a new PC with a fresh installation of linux Mint 20.2. I carried over all of the modifications that I thought I'd done to the old system into the new one. This includes:

- /usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev
- /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml
- /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us

All my modifications work on the new PC, apart from the grave accent one. Apparently, this particular setting is done elsewhere.

I checked the modifications of the desktop keyboard mappings: `dconf dump` does not reveal anything related to the accent key.

Basically, I need to reverse engineer how I managed to remap that key on the old system. It would be really great if someone could give me a hint either how to configure such mapping or where to look for the possible other modifications I could have applied on the old system outside of what is available in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/`.